# ngnix www to no-www on config file generated by certbot

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to get requests to example.com as well as www.example.com to go to https://example.com in the configuration file shown below. The file is exactly as generated by certbot.

Changing the two `return 301` statements to

```
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
```

did not work as https://www.example.com still goes to https://www.example.com and not the desired https://example.com

Would appreciate if someone could point out the exact changes needed to get the desired result. Simplified instructions would be a bonus as I am quite new to both nginx and certbot. Thanks.

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/drupal;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;        
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now, @flaixman. I made one change from your suggestion - which was to make just one block for 80, since they both did exactly the same thing. So, here's the final version : (I have hopefully not messed up something which might cause a problem later.)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server{
    root /var/www/html/d8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;        
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the brackets for a clearer way.

Instead of one 443 listener, create 2. Same with the 80 ones.

Like that it's much easier for you to know what is doing what, one configuration for each pair of host and schema.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  www.example.com; #this will only listen to http://www.example.com
    location / {        
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; #and will upgrade to https
    }
       #we don't want that many redirects, so this will go directly to example.com
 }

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com; #this will only listen to http://example.com
    location / {        
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri; #and will upgrade to https
    }
 }
server {
server_name  www.example.com;

location / {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri #this redirects to non-www
}
listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server{
#same server configuration as your first server bracket, only accepting     https://example.com and not www.
}
```

I see that you are sending the arriving connection to a Drupal so think that the Drupal has a variable $base_url that any redirect that it makes it's made to that host, so if it's set to www.example.com, it won't matter you nginx conf, as Drupal itself can also make redirects.

Hope it helped, comment for any question.

Comment: Great observation about Drupal, but I have some non-Drupal domains, and would prefer similar config files. Your suggestion worked, thanks! But some questions for fine-tuning - (1) Do I need two listeners for 80, as example.com and www.example.com both go to https: //example.com - presumably because of the `if ($host = ...)` statements. (2) Also, would I have to replicate the entire block for 443, including the _root_, _index_, and all the _location_ statements? Or can I get away with keeping just one 443 block with `if ($host = example.com ...)` statements which seem to work in the 80 block?

Comment: Hi, 

Separating blocks means a clear vision of what is happening in your nginx, with "ifs" and other conditionals you can even put all the domains in the same server block{} . In reality, yeah, you can join both domains on a 2 server block{}, one for 80 and the other for 443.

The 443 block is "special". 

You don't need root nor index in the www block ,as you are not going to direct it to your aplication, you will only need that block to redirect to non-www. The only thing you will need is the certificate (as a non secured middle redirection means the whole connection is not secure).

Comment: So you need what port to listen, what domain name to listen, certificate of that domain, and where to redirect, as you won't need to go to your aplication to search any index nor put a root where to go (as the https non-www domain is the only one that will bring the connection to the application). AS for why separating blocks is the same as trying to do a whole script in the same line, it can work, it will work, but when you come back 2 months after, you will hate yourself for doing that like that, and not clear and spaced.

Glad I helped :)

Comment: Got it! Makes sense. Shall follow your wise advice :)